# error gen_calibration.py: unable to read 32db.xml

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have successfully installed ROS on ubuntu and following the tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20Velodyne%20VLP16
but have a error gen_calibration.py: unable to read 32db.xm lon view data. I have a vlp 16 velodyne and using kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/283755/error-gen_calibration.py:-unable-to-read-32db.xml/) by [Zephyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/33883/zephyr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Most likely ROS cannot find the 32db.xml file, however if you're using a VLP16 you should be using a different calibration file.  If I'm not mistaken, the `32db.xml` file is for the HDL-32E Velodyne LiDAR.  For a VLP16 you'll need the `VeloView-VLP-16-HiRes.xml` file that came on the USB flash drive or CD that was included with your LiDAR.  So if you run this step wherever you place the calibration xml, your command would look like this:

```
rosrun velodyne_pointcloud gen_calibration.py VeloView-VLP-16-HiRes.xml
```

When running the next command in the tutorial, you'll also want to use the `VLP16_points.launch` instead of `32e_points.launch`  So the next command you should run is:

```
roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP16_points.launch calibration:={Path to}\VeloView-VLP-16-HiRes.yaml
```

From there, just run rviz like the tutorial says to see the pointcloud.

---

Originally posted by [WillGrayMSU](https://answers.ros.org/users/33891/willgraymsu/) with karma: 36 on 2018-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zephyr](https://answers.ros.org/users/33883/zephyr/) on 2018-03-05**:
when i run roslaunch command it hangs on process[velodyne_nodelet_manager_laserscan-4]: started with pid [2135]